# Find matrix of linear map from polynomial space to R

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

For the question below, would it be enough to show that the null space of $T$ is equal to $0$ for part b) and how could I show this?  I am also having trouble finding the matrix for part a).  $P_3$ refers to to the polynomial with up to degree $3$.

> for the linear map
>
> $$T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R^4}, p\mapsto \big(p(0), p(1), p\prime(0), p\prime(1)  \big)$$
>
> a) Find the matrix $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ of $T$ relative to the standard bases of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and of $\mathbb{R^4}$
>
> b) Show that $T$ is an isomorphism

Comment: It would be enough to show that the null space of $T$ is zero. Just put $T(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) = 0$ and see what this implies about $a,b,c,d$. For the matrix, do you know how to find the matrix of a linear transformation, given a basis of both the domain and codomain space?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply  $T $ to standard basis elements for  $P_3$ and see what you get...  These should be the columns of your matrix. ..

For the second part,  it looks pretty straightforward that $T(p)=0 \implies p=0$ because  $p (0)=a_0$ and $p'(0)=a_1$.  Also, $p(1)=a_3+a_2+a_1 $ and $p'(1)=3a_3+2a_2$.  It is easy from this that all $a_i =0$.  (Of course $p(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ here )